# All incoming gmail email is preceded by the text : Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently

Tags: gmail

All the incoming emails on the gmail account is preceded by the text :  Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently.

They are all forwarded by Mail Delivery Subsystem

This is happening since this morning

Comment: One for Google to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The email bounced for one of the recipients. If there's an email address listed then that's your culprit. Check if it's a correct address. If it is, it could be that the mail server for this recipient is down or perhaps there's some DNS error or whatever that makes the mail server unavailable.

Since this is GMail, check this [Google Search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&num=100&newwindow=1&q=site:google.com+"Delivery+to+the+following+recipient+failed+permanently"&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=) which I added simply because this list is way too long to just list here. Basically, there are way too many possibilities for this problem.

Link that doesn't link? [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&num=100&newwindow=1&q=site:google.com+"Delivery+to+the+following+recipient+failed+permanently"&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=)